# Matlab SVM custom kernel function

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, svm

In the Matlab [SVM tutorial](http://cn.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html#namevaluepairarguments), it says

> You can set your own kernel function, for example, kernel, by setting 'KernelFunction','kernel'. kernel must have the following form:
>
> function G = kernel(U,V)
>
> where:
>
> U is an m-by-p matrix.
> V is an n-by-p matrix.
> G is an m-by-n Gram matrix of the rows of U and V.

When I followed the custom SVM kernel [example](http://cn.mathworks.com/help/stats/support-vector-machines-svm.html?searchHighlight=SVM#buax656-1), I set a break point in mysigmoid.m function. However, I found U and V were in fact 1-by-p vectors and G was a scalar.

Why does not MATLAB process the kernel by matrices?

My custom kernel function is

```
function G = mysigmoid(U,V)
% Sigmoid kernel function with slope gamma and intercept c
gamma = 0.5;
c = -1;
G = tanh(gamma*U*V' + c);
end
```

My Matlab script is

```
%% Train SVM Classifiers Using a Custom Kernel

rng(1); % For reproducibility
n = 100; % Number of points per quadrant

r1 = sqrt(rand(2*n,1)); % Random radius
t1 = [pi/2*rand(n,1); (pi/2*rand(n,1)+pi)]; % Random angles for Q1 and Q3
X1 = [r1.*cos(t1), r1.*sin(t1)]; % Polar-to-Cartesian conversion

r2 = sqrt(rand(2*n,1));
t2 = [pi/2*rand(n,1)+pi/2; (pi/2*rand(n,1)-pi/2)]; % Random angles for Q2 and Q4
X2 = [r2.*cos(t2), r2.*sin(t2)];

X = [X1; X2]; % Predictors
Y = ones(4*n,1);
Y(2*n + 1:end) = -1; % Labels

% Plot the data
figure(1);
gscatter(X(:,1),X(:,2),Y);
title('Scatter Diagram of Simulated Data');

SVMModel1 = fitcsvm(X,Y,'KernelFunction','mysigmoid','Standardize',true);

% Compute the scores over a grid
d = 0.02; % Step size of the grid
[x1Grid,x2Grid] = meshgrid(min(X(:,1)):d:max(X(:,1)),...
min(X(:,2)):d:max(X(:,2)));
xGrid = [x1Grid(:),x2Grid(:)]; % The grid
[~,scores1] = predict(SVMModel1,xGrid); % The scores

figure(2);
h(1:2) = gscatter(X(:,1),X(:,2),Y);
hold on;
h(3) = plot(X(SVMModel1.IsSupportVector,1),X(SVMModel1.IsSupportVector,2),...
'ko','MarkerSize',10);
% Support vectors
contour(x1Grid,x2Grid,reshape(scores1(:,2),size(x1Grid)),[0,0],'k');
% Decision boundary
title('Scatter Diagram with the Decision Boundary');
legend({'-1','1','Support Vectors'},'Location','Best');
hold off;

CVSVMModel1 = crossval(SVMModel1);
misclass1 = kfoldLoss(CVSVMModel1);
disp(misclass1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Kernels add dimensions to a feature. If you have, for example, one feature for sample `x={a}` it will expand it into something like `x= {a_1... a_q}`. As you are doing this for all of your data at once, you are going to have a `M x P` (`M` is the number of examples in your training set and `P` is the number of features). The second matrix it asks for is `P x N`, where `N` is the number of examples in the training/test set.

That said, your output should be `M x N`. Since it is instead `1`, it means that you have `U = 1XM` and `V=Nx1` where `N=M`. To have an output of `M x N` logic follows that you should simply transpose your inputs.

Comment: The kernel function has the fixed format as 'mysigmoid' shows. I cannot use the kernel function directly. It is included in MATLAB SVM frame when I call `SVMModel1 = fitcsvm(X,Y,'KernelFunction','mysigmoid','Standardize',true)`.

Comment: change `G = tanh(gamma*U*V' + c);` to `G = tanh(gamma*U'*V + c);`

Comment: This does not solve the problem. In the demo, my training data is X, a 200 x 2 matrix, so U and V are expected to be exactly X and `G = U*V'` is a 200 x 200 matrix (the Gram matrix). But now U and V are both 1 x 2, so `U'*V` only construct a 2 x 2 matrix, which is not what I want.

Comment: Yes you are right, when you train, U and V are X (when testing this is not the case). Your kernel is then `G= X * X'` as X is `200 x 2 ` X' is then  `2 x 200` so you get the expected  `200 x 200 ` as output size of G. I have no idea where you are getting "U and V are `1 x 2`".

Comment: No, not quite. If your input is `200 x 2` then your kernel functions gets inputs of size `p x 2` and `q x 2` and quite often `p` and `q` are equal to 1. I did some tracing here, and in my case in the first 97 call to my kernel function p and q are 1 and after that in the last 22 calls p changes to 97. Why this is so I cannot say, because my function is called from some Java class, where I can't debug into, but that's what I can observe.